# Blank screen after software update on ubuntu 13.04

Tags: updates, 13.04

I installed Ubuntu 13.04 just after it's release.
It was going fine untill an update of some kind screwed it up.
After software update my desktop panel and launcher disappeared, I'm staring at a blank screen and can use the machine with just terminal commands.
This is my third clean install.
I can't seem to get the launcher working.
It's not about video drivers, i'm using proprietary drivers, open source one causes black screen and fglrx gives me unsupported hardware watermark.
And of course it was working thus far.
Catalyst version is 13.4
I repaired broken packages and tried to get in with failsafe graphics mode, no luck.

What can I do to fix this?

My system specifications:

- AMD FX-8350
- Asus Crosshair V Formula
- AMD Radeon HD6950
- 8 GB RAM 1600 mhz

Answer (score 1):

Actually it is about video drivers. Catalyst version 13.4 supports xorg only up to 1.13.

> As of April 26, 2013, Catalyst packages are no longer offered in the
>   official repositories. In the past, Catalyst has been dropped from
>   official Arch support because of dissatisfaction with the quality and
>   speed of development. This time, it's the incompatibility with Xorg
>   1.14.

look at: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/AMD_Catalyst

hope that will help you m8.

Comment: Welcome to askubuntu. How would this statement about Arch Linux apply to Ubuntu Linux?

Comment: It states about Catalyst incompability with XOrg higher than 1.13, just as a source of the quote.